# Is the system property user.home reliable in the current version of Java?

Tags: java, cross-platform

I need to know if it works correctly for windows (xp, vista/7), mac and some flavors of linux.

I know it's been discussed a lot on this site but:

- bugs.sun.com is not working atm, or it has changed ...
- I'm looking for recent developments

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I definitely saw it working on XP and Win7 and all flavors of Linux I tried. If you wish to test it on specific version of linux I'd recommend you to find VM image for this version and try there.

What probably can be a problem is if current user does not have a home directory at all. I know it is possible but unfortunately I do not have such user account available right now to try this.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard no word to the effect that it does not work.

To test it locally, I visited [property applet showing `java.version`, `os.name`, `os.version`, `user.home`](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.version%2Cos.name%2Cos.version%2Cuser.home&trusted=on&format=TSV)

Which returns the following results.

```
Name    Value
java.version    1.6.0_26
os.name Windows 7
os.version  6.1
user.home   C:\Users\Andrew
```

That information is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is working correctly.

But don't forget that it can always be overridden when starting the JVM:

```
java -Duser.home=/some/other/home MainClass
```